# React popup with router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, bootstrap-modal, react-redux-form

I have a redux store named as `cart` and once I click checkout button I am moving to another route order summary. I want to keep cart alive because if I click back button on order summary it must show me the cart with stored data?
Please help how can I do this?

Comment: This question is too vague. Please provide code (or at least the approach you have implemented), and what you have tried already. Or better yet, read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you unmounting/remounting the app on route change? What are you using for your router? Your state should not erase on route changes unless you are doing it on purpose or the components are unmounting.